# How do you add headers to a response with a middleware?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I can't figure out how to how to add headers to a response from a middleware. I've used both `->header(...)` and `->headers->set(...)` but both gives errors. So how do you do it?

First I tried with

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
    $response = $next($request);

    $response->headers->set('refresh', '5;url=' . route('foo'));

    return $response;
}
```

which is the same as in `Illuminate\Http\Middleware\FrameGuard.php`, but that gives

> Call to a member function set() on a non-object

Second I tried with

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
    $response = $next($request);

    $response->header('refresh', '5;url=' . route('foo'));

    return $response;
}
```

But that gives

> Method [header] does not exist on view.

So how do you add headers from a middleware?

Comment: Try debug, execute the following code 
echo get_class($response); print_r(get_class_methods($response));
What you see ?

Comment: Second option it works using `$response->header->set('refresh','...')` instead of `$response->header('refresh','...')`. [Explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29289684/3549317)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I solved this by using the `response` helper.

```
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;

$response = $next($request);
$response = $response instanceof RedirectResponse ? $response : response($response);

return $response->header('refresh', '5;url=' . route('foo'));
```

All my other middleware seems to run fine with this so I guess it's fine.

Comment: You probably better check for: `instanceof Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response` so you got every kind of response covered.

Comment: Should it check against `Illuminate\Http\Response`?

Comment: Checking to see instanceof was a big help in trying to get CORS working. Thanks!

Answer (score 21):

Here is a solution tested in **Laravel 5.0** to attach headers to routes

Create a middleware file `app/Http/Middleware/API.php`

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
class API {

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

            $response = $next($request);
            $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Content-Type, Content-Range, Content-Disposition, Content-Description, X-Auth-Token');
            $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
            //add more headers here
            return $response;
        }
}
```

Add middlewear to kernel file by adding these lines to  `/app/Http/Kernel.php`

```
protected $middleware = [
    //... some middleware here already 
    '\App\Http\Middleware\API',// <<< add this line if you wish to apply globally
];
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    //... some routeMiddleware here already 
    'api' => '\App\Http\Middleware\API', // <<< add this line if you wish to apply to your application only
];
```

Group your routes in the routes file `/app/Http/routes.php`

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'api'], function () {
    Route::get('api', 'ApiController@index');
    //other routes 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

it works too, just add to middlware:

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $request->headers->set('accept', 'application/json', true);

    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: you're adding this for request and not for response

Answer (score 1):

@marwelln's answer is partially correct for our use case, because after applying that, it causes the header content to be sent to web before blade content. This is what we get in the browser

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control:           no-cache, private
Content-Type:            text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:                    Sat, 01 Oct 2022 13:37:04 GMT

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
...
```

As this only happens when we tried to download a file in the controller using `response()->download(...)`, the solutions that works for us is

```php
  $response = $next($request);
  if ($response instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse) {
    $response = response($response);
  }
  $response->header(...);
```

However take note that some of the header seems to corrupt the downloaded file (which is a zip file for our case).