# BinaryFileResponse in Laravel undefined

Tags: php, laravel

I have got the following problem:
I want to return an Image on the route /getImage/{id}
The function looks like this:

```
public function getImage($id){
   $image = Image::find($id);
   return response()->download('/srv/www/example.com/api/public/images/'.$image->filename);
}
```

When I do this it returns me this:

```
FatalErrorException in HandleCors.php line 18:
Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse::header()
```

I have got `use Response;` at the beginning of the controller.
I dont think that the HandleCors.php is the problem but anyway:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\Middleware;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

class CORS implements Middleware {

public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
      return $next($request)->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin' , '*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With, Application');
     }
}
```

I actually dont know why this happens since it is exactly like it is described in the Laravel Docs.
I have updated Laravel when I got the error but this did not fix it.

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Version 5.0.21 after the update and before 5.0.14

Comment: You should be using `return response()->download(public_path("images/'.$image->filename"));` or something similar.

Comment: well, the error seems pretty right: you cannot set an header of the $request, only of the Response..

Comment: And what is the solution because I am not sure what to do at the moment?

Comment: instead of  
   return $next($request)->header....
try
   return ( new Response($next($request) ) )->header....

Comment: I have done that but my the BinaryFileResponse method is still undefined now. Also if I now try any other GET route I have done I see all the CORS config stuff in the Response and not only the JSON.

Comment: have you tried the solution suggested by DutGRIFF?

Comment: I did revert all changes and tried what DutGriff suggested. I did need to remove the ' and the . because the filename was not right but when I got the right filename it again told me the the method is undefined.

Comment: The response given by @DutGRIFF, while obviously a better way to do it, doesn't solve the problem in the middleware.

Comment: Mine comment was a side note. I am not sure the way you have it will not work. I just know it isn't a good way to do it.

Comment: @DutGRIFF yep totally agree. I was just clarifying that to the other user.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling `->header()` on a `Response` object that doesn't have that function (the `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse` class). The `->header()` function is [part of a trait](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/b073237d341549ada2f13e8e5b1d6d98f93428ec/src/Illuminate/Http/ResponseTrait.php#L15-L19) that is used by Laravel's [Response class](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Http/Response.php), not the base Symfony Response.

Fortunately, you have access to the `headers` property, so you can do this:

```
$response = $next($request);

$response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin' , '*');
$response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
$response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With, Application');

return $response;
```

Comment: I changed it like you said and it really did help but now get "Trying to get property of non-object" error in the second line.

Comment: @Sebi55 eh my bad. Clearly `->set()` isn't chainable.

Comment: Yeah that was my idea too. Any other idea how to fix the middleware to work with the BinaryFileResponse?

Comment: I don't understand your answer particularly but it worked for me. :)

Comment: @treeface, It worked for me thanks, but it didn't work before adding semicolon to each statements. can you please add semicolon for each of the statements?. It will be helpful for future users

Comment: Did you have any CORS problems with that solution?

Comment: dont forget `headers` not `header`

Comment: $response = $next($request);
$response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin' , '*');
$response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');$response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With, Application');$response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'nocache,no-store,max-age=0,must-revalidate');
$response->headers->set('Pragma', 'no-cache');$response->headers->set('Expires', 'Sun, 02 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT');
return $response;

Answer (score 14):

You may want to exclude headers or set different headers for `file` download requests by checking the `header` method exists in the returned `Closure`.

File download requests typically have the `header` method omitted from `Closure`.

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $handle = $next($request);

    if(method_exists($handle, 'header'))
    {
        $handle->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin' , '*')
               ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE')
               ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With, Application');
    }

    return $handle;
    
}
```

If you need to set headers for a `file` request (as other answer suggested) `$handle->headers->set()` can be used in an `else` condition:

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $handle = $next($request);

    if(method_exists($handle, 'header'))
    {
        // Standard HTTP request.

        $handle->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin' , '*');

        return $handle;
    }

    // Download Request?

    $handle->headers->set('Some-Other-Header' , 'value')

    return $handle;
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have created middleware to prevent back history and now when you want to download a file, you are getting the following error: Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse::header()

You should therefore edit yout PreventBackHistory file to:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
 
        $headers = [
            'Cache-Control'      => 'nocache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate',
            'Pragma'     => 'no-cache',
            'Expires' => 'Sun, 02 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT'
        ];
        $response = $next($request);
        foreach($headers as $key => $value) {
            $response->headers->set($key, $value);
        }
 
        return $response;       
    }
```

Inside your CORS.php file that you have created you should put the following lines of code:

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin' , '*');
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With, Application');
        
        return $response;
     }
```

Comment: Changing the prevent back history file resolved the issue for us...

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me! I hope it will be helpful.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
        
        $response = $next($request);
        $headers = [
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => '*',
        ];

        foreach($headers as $key => $value) {
            $response->headers->set($key, $value);
        }

        return $response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*use this method it's work
for me*

public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{

```
        $headers = [
'Cache-Control'      => 'nocache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate',
'Pragma'     => 'no-cache',
'Expires' => 'Sun, 02 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT'
                 ];
        $response = $next($req**strong text**uest);## Heading ##
       foreach($headers as $key => $value) {
        $response->headers->set($key, $value);
          }

        return $response;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your PreventBackHistory to allow your browser to download the excel sheet:

```
if ($response instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse) {
        $response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
        $response->headers->set('Pragma', 'no-cache');
        $response->headers->set('Expires', 'Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT');
        return $response;
    }else{
        return $response->header('Cache-Control','nocache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate')
            ->header('Pragma','no-cache')
            ->header('Expires','Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); 
    }
```