# Error when returning image in Laravel API

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following code snippet.

```
public function open(Request $request, $send)
{
   
    // $send = Storage::disk('images')->get('track.png');

    return response()->file(public_path('images/track.png'));
}
```

And it returns the following error

> ```
> Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse:: header()
> ```

My Laravel is 7.

What am I doing wrong which is resulting in this error?

Comment: have you added any middleware to your project or is this a relatively clean install and you are getting this error after just returning that file response? there are middleware that need to access the headers of responses in the stack .. is it possible you could provide part of the stacktrace?

Comment: Have you tried setting up the headers? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53981612/call-to-undefined-method-binaryfileresponseheader