# Can't download files from public folder from Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel-5, download, storage

I don't know what I am doing wrong here, but I can't for the life of me manage to get the download feature to work in Laravel 5.6

I have files saved to the public folder as you can see below:

[image]

On the webpage, these images show up correctly in HTML `<img>` tags and when I view the details of the image, it shows me that it points to `https://mydomain.test/storage/LIizYnRWEqYOgTPlzTxbmuSbTMNYIFrnjLP1YWVH.png`.

However, when I try and download this file from the server, I constantly get an exception error about the file not existing (for example: `"data":"The file \"public\/LIizYnRWEqYOgTPlzTxbmuSbTMNYIFrnjLP1YWVH.png\" does not exist")`. I have tried every combination of path string I can think of, but everything results in the same error.

I have tried using `storage_path`, I have tried using the original path, I've tried hard coding the path

```
    [2022-09-08 09:58:55] local.ERROR: Failed to download media file: The file "/home/vagrant/Code/dras/storage/LIizYnRWEqYOgTPlzTxbmuSbTMNYIFrnjLP1YWVH.png" does not exist  
    [2022-09-08 09:59:38] local.ERROR: Failed to download media file: The file "public/LIizYnRWEqYOgTPlzTxbmuSbTMNYIFrnjLP1YWVH.png" does not exist  
    [2022-09-08 10:00:14] local.ERROR: Failed to download media file: The file "https://mydomain.test/storage/LIizYnRWEqYOgTPlzTxbmuSbTMNYIFrnjLP1YWVH.png" does not exist   
    [2022-09-08 10:17:18] local.ERROR: Failed to download media file: The file "app/public/LIizYnRWEqYOgTPlzTxbmuSbTMNYIFrnjLP1YWVH.png" does not exist
    [2022-09-08 10:45:50] local.ERROR: Failed to download media file: The file "storage/public/LIizYnRWEqYOgTPlzTxbmuSbTMNYIFrnjLP1YWVH.png" does not exist
```

The only combination that doesn't throw an exception about "file does not exist" is when I use the path

`return response()->download( 'storage/LIizYnRWEqYOgTPlzTxbmuSbTMNYIFrnjLP1YWVH.png' );`

However, that command throws a totally different error:

`Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse::header() in file /home/vagrant/Code/dras/app/Http/Middleware/Cors.php on line 27`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path:"public/LIizYnRWEqYOgTPlzTxbmuSbTMNYIFrnjLP1YWVH.png\  implies the conflict between windows and linux systems. There cant be both / and \ in a path. it must be either or. Unfortunately, i have been there and there is no easy way to get past this. you must use str_replace method to manually replace either (/) or () with the other. Check what your OS views as a valid file path first. it should be either: \public\LIizYnRWEqYOgTPlzTxbmuSbTMNYIFrnjLP1YWVH.png
or
/public/LIizYnRWEqYOgTPlzTxbmuSbTMNYIFrnjLP1YWVH.png

Edit: For future reference, this is what finally resolved the problem,

[BinaryFileResponse in Laravel undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29289177/binaryfileresponse-in-laravel-undefined)

Comment: I don't know why it's showing the \ at the start and end of the string.  When I export the actual path of the image to Laravel.log it comes out correctly: `[2022-09-08 13:53:55] local.INFO: /home/vagrant/Code/dras/public/LIizYnRWEqYOgTPlzTxbmuSbTMNYIFrnjLP1YWVH.png`

Comment: As soon as I use `Storeage::download()` or set the path as `storage/LIizYnRWEqYOgTPlzTxbmuSbTMNYIFrnjLP1YWVH.png` I get the exception error with `cors.php` as mentioned above.  Everything else fails with file does not exist.

Comment: (I don't know why it's showing the \ at the start and end of the string.)- As I said, linux systems will often use that format in their equivalent of file explorer. unfortunately, this is not something you can change.

Comment: This should help with the Binary Response: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29289177/binaryfileresponse-in-laravel-undefined

Comment: Thank you for your assistance on this issue. Your comments helped me solve the problem.  Whilst I don't believe it ended up being a pathing issue like you suggested, however, your last link to the Binary Response was what was solved it instantly.

Comment: Glad to be of help. I have edited the answer for future readers. Please accept it as the correct answer or make one of your own detailing the process of how you resolved it for future readers. Thank you.